# Button to start activity if statement

Tags: java, android, button

I want the button to open a dialog only if the content equals to America. How do I do it?
I've tried creating a dialog activity and then using an intent I got the dialog box but it appeared separately and not over the current activity!

```
if(check.contentEquals("america")){

                           // Then I want the dialog to open here
```

Comment: You already have it done, run your dialogue code within the if statement :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if(check.contentEquals("america")){
            imageview.setAlpha(0);
            Intent i = new Intent(ACTION NAME);
            startActivity(i);
}
```

if you want to run a simple dialog all you have to do is:

```
if(check.contentEquals("america")){
            imageview.setAlpha(0);
            mDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to display an alert dialog try this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setCancelable(true);
builder.setTitle("Title");
builder.setMessage("your message");
builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override 
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
     dialog.dismiss();
  }
});
final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

if(check.contentEquals("america")){
   alert.show();
}
```

Comment: I want a AlertDialog that has been placed in another activity to open in the current activity?

Comment: no, you can declare it in the current activity.kindly accept my answer if you were able to figure out it :)

Comment: I'm designing a game. To save the last activity state I have added a menu with 2 buttons- Save and Load Everyone time the person clicks the save button I want the activity state to be saved, and when the app is launched again and the user clicks the load button in the menu , I want the activity state to be Loaded! Is it possible? Please do give examples with entire code!